# have_post() does return null value in wp

Tags: wordpress, blog-post

I used the following code in my page template:

```
<?php
while(have_posts()):the_post();
the_content();
?>
```

But nothing is displayed. The loop is not working. I'm sure that, there is sufficient information as content in my template page.

Comment: did you close the while loop?

Comment: Please add complete code, your code block is incomplete. We cannot make the clear concept of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use if condition to check if post exists else skip the loop. Make sure to ON the error log and check the exact error.

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: it was i tried. I got the error message.. But actually I have value in my post. The same code is working in another pages.

Comment: After putting your code I just got a message like "Sorry, no posts matched your criteria."

Comment: seems you need to reset query there. I have edited the code. please check.

Comment: ya its right. after adding <?php wp_reset_query()?> after while loop, it became ok.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: My Template
*/

the_post();
the_content();
?>
```

If you save the following code as a page template and call the page template into a **page** by choosing it, then the page will show the page content without any hassle.

Note: it's *THE* minimal bit of code.

Answer (score 2):

use the following code
Try using wp_reset_query()

```
 <?php
    wp_reset_query();
    while(have_posts()):the_post();
    the_content();
    endwhile;
   ?>
```